# Law of two stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-integrals

Suppose we are given two filtered probability spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal F, (\mathcal F_t)_t, \mathbb P)$ and $(\Omega', \mathcal F', (\mathcal F'_t)_t, \mathbb P')$. On $\Omega$ (respectively $\Omega'$) we are a given a standard Wiener process $W$ (respectively $W'$) adapted to the filtration.
Suppose also to have a stochastic process $(X_t)_t$ on $\Omega$ such that it makes sense to define its Ito integral $\int_0^T X(t)dW(t)$. Suppose similarly to have a stochastic process $(X'_t)_t$ on $\Omega'$ such that it makes sense to define its Ito integral $\int_0^T X'(t)dW'(t)$. Finally, assume that $X_t \stackrel{d}{=}X'_t$ for any $t$.

Question: is it true that $$\int_0^T X(t)dW(t) \stackrel{d}{=} \int_0^T X'(t)dW'(t)$$
holds? Intuitively, it seems true to me, but I cannot find a proof for it.

Comment: Yes it's true. Prove the statement for elementary process first, and then approximate $X_t$ and $X_t'$ by elementary process to conclude.

Comment: I see, it's easier than I thought... Do you have a reference for this fact?

Comment: No need reference, you have all elements to prove it your self...